# CMPedometer : queryPedometerData stuck to 9251 value

Tags: ios, swift, pedometer

I query the `CMPedometer`, i've done lot of test with differents `Date()` and `CMPedometer.queryPedometerData` never return more than 9251 steps.

For exemple if I query for each day (Date() to Date - 1, -2 ... 10) when 9251 steps is reached all my next steps will be 0.

```
 self.pedometer?.queryPedometerData(from: dateStart, to: dateEnd, withHandler: { (data, error) -> Void in
        if let numberOfSteps = data?.numberOfSteps.intValue{
            print("\(numberOfSteps))")
        }
    })
```

Something has changed ? I can't found nothing about this problem. It worked a few days ago, looks like bug from the apple API if someone can confirm it :(

Comment: Any luck solving the problem?

Comment: @YaronLevi No, just a bug wich has disappeared few days later without reason. Sorry :(